# "Jewelry By Jan" or "Jewelries By Jan", the correct brand name considering they design more than one type of jewelry?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

considering that the person designs **more than one type** of jewelry, is the brand name "**Jewelry** By Jan" grammatically correct? Or it has to be "**Jewelries** By Jan" instead? Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of spelling, jewellery/jewelry is [not normally considered "countable"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/jewelry#:~:text=%2F%CB%88d%CA%92u%C9%99lri%2F,some%20lovely%20pieces%20of%20jewelry.) in English. So "Jewellery by Jan" would encompass multiple ***pieces*** of jewellery as well as potentially multiple ***types*** of pieces of jewellery. English has no succinct natural way of distinguishing "more than one piece of jewellery of the same type" from "more than one piece of jewellery of *different* types".

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh wow, thanks! I didn't know the word "jewellery" is uncountable because I'm pretty sure I 've heard the word "jewelries" so many times. Thank you!

Comment: I originally voted to *close* this question, because it just so happens the first dictionary definition I checked (Oxford Advanced Learner's) did in fact explicitly mention "uncountable". But having seen your comment, ***and*** looked at a few more dictionaries (Collins also mentions "uncountable", but neither Merriam-Webster nor Cambridge do), I have retracted my closevote. It now seems likely to me that this question ***will*** be useful to future visitors who may struggle for the same reasons you have.

Comment: Who is using this *jewelries*?

Comment: @FeliniusRex: [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jewelries#:~:text=(%CB%88d%CA%92u%20%C9%99l%20ri),Compare%20costume%20jewelry.) cites at least three instances: *a complete range of jewelries for wearing on different occasions, a leading wholesaler and manufacturer of premium jewelries in Hong Kong* and *it is needless to record the jewelries one by one*. They may not *exactly* be from "authoritative sources", but there's certainly enough there to justify OP's doubts and confusion.

Comment: ...and [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jewelries%2Cjewelleries&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) an NGram showing that both plural spellings have been steadily gaining traction over the past couple of centuries, even among what I would suppose are "mainstream" native Anglophones.

Comment: Given that this is for a brand name I would say that either could be used though I do consider "Jewelry" the more expected form.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: Presumably because you're US-based. In [*British English*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jewelry%2Cjewellery&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3), it's nearly always still the double-L spelling (many of the "counter-examples" in that linked chart are just misclassified US-published texts anyway).

Comment: In my entire life (and I am not young(, I have never, ever heard jewelry/jewellery in the plural.